# Shapely Polygon Union with Holes Result

Tags: python, geometry, union, shapely, cascading

I'm looking for approach to merge polygons which produce holes that covers between polygons. I already tried to use cascading union in Shapely, but it gives polygon that cover holes.

Reference question : [polygon union without holes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844462/polygon-union-without-holes/51981402?noredirect=1#comment90913759_51981402)

**expected output**

[image: expected output]

Answer (score -2):

I just solved this, you can extract `list(concatenated_polygon.interiors)` and pass it to MultiPolygon Geojson object where first geometry is Polygon *Outerline* and the rest are holes *LinearRing*

Comment: Can you provide some more info on how you solved this as I'm currently facing the exact same problem? Maybe a code snippet?