# how to merge several polygons into one in java

Tags: java, eclipse, coordinates, polygon, openstreetmap

I was wondering how to programatically merge several polygons on a map as one, meaning it'd still have the same general shape but the boundaries between them was removed and they'd work as a single set of coordinates, like on that picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1ThG.png

I'm using java on eclipse and open street map for the display.

(so I have several sets of coordinates and I want to make them a single set without simplifying the general shape).

Comment: that has already been resolved, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667748/how-do-i-combine-complex-polygons and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111296/subtract-rectangle-from-polygon/111323#111323

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I don't think convex hull will work in this case,  OP does not to simplify(change) the general shape.

Comment: I do not think this should be marked as duplicate, for reasons I try to articulate in my answer below.

Comment: Since you mentioned OSM, [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/) (a Java-based OSM editor) has an implementation for [merging polygons](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Help/Action/JoinAreas). Maybe you can borrow its code.

Answer (score 1):

The [union computation](https://mathoverflow.net/a/111323/6094), as cited by @MartinFrank, would work, but is quite complex and more than is needed in this case.
Clearly if you can merge two polygons *P1* and *P2* that share some positive
length of boundary, you can merge any number.
From the image provided, it appears that the polygons may exactly (as opposed to
approximately) share boundary portions. If this is the case, then the following
would work.

Walk (loop) around the boundary of *P1*, checking if the current vertex is
also a vertex of *P2*. Once you have identified a common shared vertex *v*,
then it is easy to walk forward & backward around the two polygons until you identify starting *a* and stopping *b* vertices that delimit the extent of the shared boundary. Then delete that *ab* portion, and stitch the two remaining boundary
sections together to form *P1* union *P2*.