How to expand polygon with line segments
I have a polygon represented by an array of vertexes which each have an x and y coordinate.
I have a line which is also an array of vertexes that is fully outside of the polygon, meaning that none of its vertexes are inside. Here is a picture for reference:

What I want to do is this:


Basically, I want to expand my polygon with a line segment. I want to connect both ends of the line to the closest vertex in the polygon. (pictured with green) Then I want to traverse the vertexes of the polygon and remove all vertexes that are between the two connecting vertexes.
My current solution is this:

Detect which direction the line is going. If the line segment is going anti-clockwise then flip the order because the polygon is
always drawn clockwise
Insert the line segment vertexes after the first closest vertex (the line is going in a clockwise direction at this step)
Delete all the points between the last vertex of the line and second closest vertex

The method I use for detecting the direction is the following:

a := line[line.length - 2] - line[0], is a vector from the first vertex to the second to last vertex
b := line[line.length - 1] - line[line.length - 2] is a vector form the second to last to the last vertex
If a x b (where a x b is the cross product of vectors a and b: (a.x * b.y) - (a.y * b.x)) is less than 0 then the direction is anti-clockwise

The problem I am experiencing is the following:

In the picture above is a concave polygon and I'm attempting to draw a line that will be merged into it. The line is represented by the red squares and I drew the array as a polygon for representative purposes. Based on the algorithm above, we can state that the line is going in a clockwise direction so the order of the line vertexes will not be reversed. But this is not what is supposed to happen. The line vertexes should always be ordered in a way that when they are inserted into the polygon vertex array, the are in a clockwise direction.
This is the result after the merge:

My question is this: How do I define the function for determining the direction of the line in this context? My thinking is that I could do something with the part I'm  trying to (insert into)/replace but I'm  not sure. I'm open to new ideas but I want to implement the polygon using the array of vertexes or an equivalent to that.
Motivation: I'm trying to make a game where the player is trying to conquer as much territory as possible. The polygon is the area that player owns and they can venture out where their path will be saved into an array. When the player returns into their territory, the area they conquered will be merged into their polygon.
Update:
I cannot pick the shorter path because of this:

If I were to remove the shorter path, it would not work with this specific example.

Before you commit yourself to this "algorithm", find shapes that break the "algorithm". Only if no shapes break the "algorithm" does it then become an actual algorithm worth implementing with code.

The shape that breaks the "algorithm" is above. I'm trying to determine the proper way to insert the line segments into the polygon and delete the proper vertexes from it. Please read and understand my question before you comment or answer.

By "break" I mean find shapes where the "algorithm" no longer works. If no such shapes exist, then put in time to turn this to program code. Don't assume your algorithm is correct that is.

I don't want to read your passive aggressive comments, if you think something is wrong with the question, please point it out. I'm trying to think of a way to make this algorithm. I described the exact shape this will not work for and how my implementation breaks, exactly.

"I don't want to read your passive aggressive comments... please point it out" ... Its your job to create the algorithm. You could always of course research it as well. Where's your attitude coming from?

@ITgoldman that will not work because when you enclose the polygon with the line, it will fail. I will update the question to show why

So when you lead with "I have a line which is also an array of vertexes that is fully outside of the polygon" ... thats not a rule apparently. Thats an example of when your algorithm works. And then you proceed to show examples of when the algorithm doesn't work. ... Why not have more than one algorithm per case?

maybe you should explain the reasons behind, because you can think of many polygons that will be confusing (a donut, a spiral).

I see, I will add that to the question.

Also if you could include more of the code you tried whether its javascript or some other language because a := line[line.length - 2] - line[0] looks like Pascal. Is this a code port also?

No, I'm trying to implement this in JavaScript and it will be later ported to PHP for a multiplayer browser game. What I'm making is basically a Paper Io clone but I'm approaching it from a different angle. I used mathematical notation to be universal.

@GetSet I would rather not share it because I have to do this for a school project. The pixel method outlined in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768282/find-inside-part-algorithm-for-paper-io-game
is what the teacher wants us to use, but I'm trying a different method.
