# Generate new line coordinates using existing lines

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, line, interpolation

I am looking for a way to get the coordinates of a new line using the provided coordinates of existing 2 lines. The maximum of existing coordinates of 2 input lines should form a new line.

**sample data:**

```
line,X,Y
2,654285.7888,7515952.277
2,652460.4172,7517950.319
2,650339.0394,7517530.977
2,648489.0006,7517210.304
2,644887.5917,7516790.962
2,642544.2092,7515828.942
2,642371.5389,7513633.562
2,643654.2325,7511980.861
2,647132.3054,7510747.502
2,653348.4358,7509711.48
2,656579.8369,7509144.135
2,657467.8556,7508428.786
2,658725.8819,7511857.525
2,656826.5088,7514348.91
1,655963.1573,7516001.612
1,652805.7578,7517234.971
1,649993.6988,7517703.648
1,646194.9524,7516741.627
1,643234.8903,7515335.598
1,643259.5575,7511413.516
1,647872.321,7509908.817
1,651868.4048,7510500.83
1,656530.5026,7509538.81
1,659095.8897,7512079.53
1,658109.2023,7514620.25
```

Plotting these coordinates for each line gives the following two lines:
[image: line 1 and line 2]

The objective is to manipulate the **Line 1** (blue) given by the **Line 2** (orange), i.e. outer most of these 2 lines should form a new line and get coordinates for that new line. The expected new line, **Line 3** (black) should be like below:

[image: expected line 3]

Any help in providing an approach or guiding towards right resource would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Merging polygons --> https://deparkes.co.uk/2015/02/28/how-to-merge-polygons-in-python/

Comment: also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667748/how-do-i-combine-complex-polygons/19475433#19475433 , and there: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111296/subtract-rectangle-from-polygon/111323#111323 , ansd here too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15815/how-to-union-many-polygons-efficiently

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is well defined. To solve this, it's first necessary to formulate in an unambiguous mathematical way which points are "outer".